# Highcharts tick interval positioning

Tags: jquery, api, highcharts, intervals

The tick intervals on my graph are not aligned with the graph lines, this occurred when I increased the height of the graph (which is a design requirement). I've read through and tried out Highcharts [tick positioner info](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions) but this isn't exactly what I want, is it possible to position where the numbers are placed? they need pushing up to align them.

Here's a screenshot:

*Edit*

Here's the code on a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tWpT6/) - sorry can't get in running properly on there

I can't see anything on the yAxis settings that would be affecting it

`yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                labels: {
                    format: '{value}%',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: 26,
                    }
                },
                gridLineColor: '#f7a600',
                gridLineWidth: 2,
                tickInterval: tickIntervalNumber,
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },`

I don't think the if statement at the top would affect it either but I could be wrong

`//tick inteval variable
    if (total > 200) {
        var tickIntervalNumber = 200 / 4
    }
    else {
        var tickIntervalNumber = 100 / 4
    }`

[image]

Comment: it would help if we could see your chart code, or a jsfiddle showing the problem.

Comment: These are aligned - just that the number labels are below the tick line. Are you modifying the labels at all in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seing your code, I'm not sure if this is the problem, but you can adjust the label positions relative to the tick lines as follows:

```
yAxis: {
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            y:0
        }
    },
```

The 'y' options allows you to move the labels up/down relative to the tick lines.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels

Comment: thank you, I'd tried changing the y attribute of the yAxis before but not within labels, sorted now with `y:5`